# What are the limitations of using data sharing between two redshift clusters in two different accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-sharing

I know that we can share data between two redshift clusters in different accounts using datashare. I also saw that after associating the data share in the consumer account, we need to create a database from the datashare before accessing the data. So, in this case will all the cross database sharing limitations apply in the consumer account.

Below are the limitations mentioned in AWS documentation

When you work with the cross-database query feature in Amazon Redshift, be aware of the limitations following:

- When you query database objects on any other unconnected databases,
  you have read access only to those database objects.
- You can't query views that are created on other databases that refer
  to objects of yet another database.
- You can only create late-binding and materialized views on objects of
  other databases in the cluster. You can't create regular views on
  objects of other databases in the cluster.
- Amazon Redshift doesn't support tables with column-level privileges
  for cross-database queries.
- Amazon Redshift doesn't support concurrency scaling for the queries
  that read data from other databases.
- Amazon Redshift doesn't support query catalog objects on AWS Glue or
  federated databases. To query these objects, first create external
  schemas that refer to those external data sources in each database.
- Amazon Redshift doesn't support result cache for cross-database
  queries.